# How do "and" and "or" work when combined in one statement?

Tags: python, boolean-logic, if-statement

For some reason this function confused me:

```
def protocol(port):
    return port == "443" and "https://" or "http://"
```

Can somebody explain the order of what's happening behind the scenes to make this work the way it does.

I understood it as this until I tried it:

Either A)

```
def protocol(port):
    if port == "443":
        if bool("https://"):
            return True
    elif bool("http://"):
        return True
    return False
```

Or B)

```
def protocol(port):
    if port == "443":
        return True + "https://"
    else:
        return True + "http://"
```

Is this some sort of special case in Python, or am I completely misunderstanding how statements work?

Comment: @Responders, see my 1 minute later update. Sorry.

Comment: Just remember the 'and' and the 'or' statements return the last expression to be evaluated. :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's an old-ish idiom; inserting parentheses to show priority,

```
(port == "443" and "https://") or "http://"
```

`x and y` returns `y` if `x` is truish, `x` if `x` is falsish; `a or b`, vice versa, returns `a` if it's truish, otherwise `b`.

So if `port == "443"` is true, this returns the RHS of the `and`, i.e., `"https://"`.  Otherwise, the `and` is false, so the `or` gets into play and returns `"http://", *its* RHS.

In modern Python, a better way to do translate this old-ish idiom is:

```
"https://" if port == "443" else "http://"
```

Comment: @Alex +1 Thanks for the in-depth explanation. They've apparently made it so that I can't accept an answer for 10 minutes :( but great answer.

Comment: @orokusaki, thanks, and I'm sure you'll be able to accept it later;-).

Comment: +1 for mentioning python's ternary operator, much easier to read/understand imho

Comment: I learned a long time ago to use parentheses to make the interpreter/compiler do what *I* want the code to do, rather than be at the mercy of precedence. It helps to document the code for me and any who are maintaining it after I've passed it on. I consider it part of coding defensively.

Answer (score 9):

`and` returns the right operand if the left is true. `or` returns the right operand if the left is false. Otherwise they both return the left operand. They are said to **coalesce**.

Comment: Ah, thanks Ignacio. I don't know how I've gotten so far in Python without understanding this. It's the first time I've ever seen it used exactly like this. +1

Answer (score 6):

What you are really asking is what an expression like `C and X or Y` means or does. It is the long-running early attempt by Python users to proxy for `C ? X : Y`

For the most part it works, *except* if `X` is `False` -- this has led to many bugs in Python code, so in the [Python FAQ](http://www.python.org/doc/faq/programming/#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator), you'll find the more correct solution being `(C and [X] or [Y])[0]` because a list with a single element, regardless of its evaluated Boolean value, is always `True`! For example: `[None]` is `True` but `None` isn't. The OP's example above works because the string representing `X` is not empty.

However, all this changed in Python 2.5, when the ternary or conditional operator was added to the language, allowing you to use the cleaner `X if C else Y` as stated in other posts here. If you see code using the older format, it's because the user has been a long time Python programmer who hasn't adopted the new syntax yet, they cut-n-paste other old code, or their employer is still using 2.4.x (or earlier releases), etc.

All that said, addressing your specific question brings up a "hidden feature" that's employed as well, so let's take a closer look at `return port == "443" and "https://" or "http://"`:

The `and` binds stronger than the `or`, meaning you can effectively imagine a pair of parentheses in this equivalent expression: `(port == "443" and "https://") or "http://"`. Furthermore, the hidden feature I referred to is known as a *short circuit* such that if both (port == "443" and "https://") are true (which they are), the `or` clause is completely ignored.   However if one or neither are true, that's the only time the `or` clause will be used.

Another observation: non-empty strings are always `True`, so `port == "443"` is the only thing that can possibly be `False`, so it is the main question being asked. If it is true, then evaluation moves to the right of the `and`, meaning `"https://"` is returned. If it is false, another short circuit happens where `"https://"` is skipped, and evaluation continues to the right of the `or`.

Bottom-line for what the code does: it checks whether `port == "443"`, and if it is, then `"https://`" is returned, otherwise `"http://"` is returned. Neither `True` nor `False` are possibly return values. The most accurate equivalent is:

```
def protocol(port):
    if port == "443":
        return "https://"
    else:
        return "http://"
```

In modern Python, you would write it like this:

```
def protocol(port):
    return "https://" if port == "443" else "http://"
```

One last assumption is that `port` is a string. A more robust version would support integer input, e.g., `return "https://" if str(port) == "443" else "http://"`.

Answer (score 2):

This is an ugly hack that is not recommended. It works because of the short-circuiting behaviour of `and` and `or` and that they return the one of their arguments rather than a boolean value. Using this technique gives a risk of introducing hard-to-find bugs, so don't use it in new code.

Here's an example of how the `and/or` idiom can give an unexpected result:

```
>>> foo = 'foobar'
>>> bar = 'foobar'
>>> x = 0
>>> y = 1
>>> (foo == bar) and x or y   # Will this return the value of x if (foo == bar)?
1
```

Prefer instead the newer notation:

```
return "https://" if port == "443" else "http://"
```

Comment: @Mark That's the version I'm familiar with, and I've never seen the version in my post until today. +1

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read up on the "and / or trick" of Python in this article [The Peculiar Nature of And and Or in Python](http://diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/and_or.html). It's a bit like the `IIF()` in VBA or VB, or `?:` in C-style languages.

Comment: @Abel Thanks. I just read it, interesting article. I've used the `return a or b` syntax plenty but for some reason this snippet does't jive.

Answer (score 0):

This construction works because it 'unfolds' to the following code:

a and b -->

```
if a:
  return b
else:
  return a
```

a or b -->

```
if a:
  return a
else:
  return b
```

Answer (score 0):

With all the good answers, I found these statements help me remember this better and fit how my brain works (and hopefully for for some more out there) :

- “and" returns the first False item (e.g., None, “”, [], (), {}, 0) or the last item if none (e.g. no False found)
- “or" returns the first True item or the last item (e.g. no True found)**

**In summary**:

- they all return the first item that decides the outcome of the statement. (In the worst case, the last item in the sequence)

Note this rule also applies to a chained all "and" or all "or" statement